# Resource Injection error in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I'm using `@PostConstruct` and a method named init to do some intialization, but when I do any kind of intialization it gives me the following error.

```
"An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean myBean"
```

Follow is the code:

```
@PostConstruct
void init() {
   myList.add("test");
}
```

Comment: full stacktrace would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

From this little amount of information you provided, I can only guess this exception occured because you didn't initialize `myList` properly.

Something like `List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();` must have been called before `myList.add("test")`.